# getStringExtra in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, laravel, android-studio

I have a laravel application. Now I need to transfer it to android. My first task is to implement rewarded video admob. The problem is that I need, after triggering the `onRewarded` method, to send a request to the server that the reward will be added according to my criteria. Since in java I'm new, I ran into a problem. I realized that `webview` and `HttpURLConnection` have different sessions. So far I've come to the conclusion that it's worth to translate `auth :: user () -> id` through cookies, I set the session, then from the session on the front I create cookies, from where I send to `webview`. The next problem is that I need to transfer these cookies to another activity. I found Intent class, through it I pass `putExtra ("ACCESS_TOKEN", CookieValue);` . The question is, how can I get and shove in the second activity. If I do this completely incorrectly, I would be happy with any prompts

```
private class apiPostCoins extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try {

                //This is what i want to reach
                String cookieValue = data.getStringExtra("ACCESS_TOKEN");
                //
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/redirect_get_coins/");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this .

**FirstActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra ("ACCESS_TOKEN", CookieValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String access_token = intent.getStringExtra("ACCESS_TOKEN");
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried with Intent intent = new Intent. Intent intent = getIntent(); helped me )